# LINQ: Select SalaryEstimates with Public Jobs Count

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 SalaryEstimates `A, B and C`

I want to output `SalaryEstimates (Number of Jobs)`

```
A (20 jobs)
B (32 jobs)
```

C will not go out bec incidentally jobs under it are not public and not deleted

Below is my code, it's able to output what I want but it's kinda long. Is there a better way?

```
var publicJobsQuery = _dbContext.Jobs
    .Where(j => j.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
    .Where(j => j.IsPrivate.Equals(false));

var jobsIdHs = new HashSet<int>(publicJobsQuery.Select(j => j.JobId));

var salaryEstimatesWithJobs = _dbContext.SalaryEstimates
    .Include(s => s.Jobs)
    .Where(s => s.Jobs.Any(j => jobsIdHs.Contains(j.JobId)))
    .Select(s => new SalaryEstimatesWithJobCountViewModel
    {
        SalaryEstimate = s,
        JobCount = s.Jobs.Count(j => jobsIdHs.Contains(j.JobId))
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could start your query by `Jobs` instead  and apply a group by:

```
var salaryEstimatesWithJobs = _dbContext.Jobs
                              .Include(s => s.SalaryEstimates)
                              .Where(j => !j.IsDeleted && !j.IsPrivate)
                              .GroupBy(e=>e.SalaryEstimateId)
                              .Select(g => new SalaryEstimatesWithJobCountViewModel
                                          {
                                           SalaryEstimate = g.FirstOrDefault().SalaryEstimate,
                                           JobCount = g.Count()
                                          });
```